# Pandas Plot floating bar chart

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

I am trying to create a bar chart where the upper and lower bound of each bar could be above or below zero. Hence the boxes should "float" depending on the data. I'm also trying to use `pandas.plot` function as it makes my life way easier in the real application.

The solution I've devised is a horrible kludge and only partially works. Basically I'm running two different bar charts that overlap, with one of the bars being white to "hide" the main bar if necessary. I'm using a `mask` to mark which bars should be which color. As you can see, this works OK in the "London" and "Paris" example below, but in the "Tokyo" it isn't working because the green bar is "in front" of the white bar.

I could manually fix this a few ways that I can think of, but it would make an already kludgy solution even worse. I'm sure there's a better way that I'm just not smart enough to think of!

Here's the plot, and full code below.

[image]

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

df_data = {'Category':['London', 'Paris', 'New York', 'Tokyo'],
            'Upper':[10, 5, 0, -5],
            'Lower':[5, -5, -10, -10]}

df = pd.DataFrame(data = df_data)

#Color corrector
u_mask = df['Upper'] < 0
d_mask = df['Lower'] < 0
n = len(df)
uca = ['darkgreen' for i in range(n)]
uca = np.array(uca)
uc = uca.copy()
uc[u_mask] = 'white'
dca = ['white' for i in range(n)]
dca = np.array(dca, dtype=uca.dtype)
dc = dca.copy()
dc[d_mask] = 'darkgreen'

(df.plot(kind='bar', y='Upper', x='Category', 
        color=uc, legend=False))
ax = plt.gca()
(df.plot(kind='bar', y='Lower', x='Category', 
        color=dc, legend=False, ax=ax))

plt.axhline(0, color='black')
x_axis = ax.xaxis
x_axis.label.set_visible(False)
plt.subplots_adjust(left=0.1,right=0.90,bottom=0.2,top=0.90)
plt.show()
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To create the plot via pandas, you could create an extra column with the height. And use `df.plot(..., y=df['Height'], bottom=df['Lower'])`:

```py
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

df_data = {'Category': ['London', 'Paris', 'New York', 'Tokyo'],
           'Upper': [10, 5, 0, -5],
           'Lower': [5, -5, -10, -10]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data=df_data)
df['Height'] = df['Upper'] - df['Lower']

ax = df.plot(kind='bar', y='Height', x='Category', bottom=df['Lower'],
             color='darkgreen', legend=False)
ax.axhline(0, color='black')
plt.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```

[image: resulting plot]

PS: Note that pandas barplot forces the lower ylim to be "sticky". This is a desired behavior when all values are positive and the bars stand firmly on `y=0`. However, this behavior is distracting when both positive and negative values are involved.

To remove the stickyness:

```py
ax.use_sticky_edges = False # df.plot() makes the lower ylim sticky
ax.autoscale(enable=True, axis='y')
```

Answer (score 0):

`plt.bar` has a `bottom` paramter. You just need to calculate the heights. Here is a very easy exampel:

```py
upper = [10, 5, 0, -5]
lower = [5, -5, -10, -10]
height = [upper[i] - lower[i] for i in range(len(upper))]

data = [1,2,3]
plt.bar(range(len(lower)),height, bottom=lower)
plt.show()
```